# vb6 creating third exe that runs the first and second exe file

Tags: vb6, hide, exe

i have 2 exe file that i want to be run simultaneously with one click. and i want to create an application in **visual basic 6** that do this for me. how i can refer to the 1 and 2 exe file in my application? (the third exe file) and is it possible to make the first and second exe file to be run only when the third (my application) is running or other solutions like hiding the two files and only make the third visible?

Note: i can not access to the first and second file source

Comment: Call the `Shell` function and specify the path to your executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the 1st and 2nd executable you could use the `Shell` function.

```
Shell("C:\YourPrograms\Program.exe", vbNormalFocus)
```

If you only wanted to open these executables if executable 3 is running you will have to do some logic in apllication 1 and 2 to check if executable 3 is in process.

Comment: The Shell command returns immediately, so you can start the second executable dircectly after the first. I cannot think of a case in which you would like to do this multithreadedly ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use Shell Function in following format:

```
RetVal = Shell([Pathname of EXE],[WindowStyle As vbAppWinStyle = vbMinimisedFocus])
```

Sample Code

```
Private Sub cmdExec_Click() ' cmdExec is the name of the command button on any form.
   Dim RetVal
   RetVal = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\System32\calc.exe", 1)    ' Run Calculator.
End Sub
```

Use ShowWindow function to hide the window.

You can use FindWindow function to check whether other application is running.

[Refer it to find window](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/72918)

[Refer API Guide to find running example to FindWindow, ShowWindow and more API's](http://allapi.mentalis.org/agnet/apiguide.shtml)